# Ultimate tic tac toe game the GUI is blank every time i run my code

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I have been trying to complete this ultimate Tic Tac toe game but i am at a loss at where i have gone wrong. my problem is that when i compile and run the code all i get is a blank GUI [Blank GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRejS.png). other then that the code is working in the back ground. its just not showing the vertical and horizontal lines that make up the game, and the pieces. id appreciate any help or just point me in the right direction thanks.

I am hoping that a fresh look at my code will see what i am missing. this is my XOBoard code

```
package javafxapplicationprototype;

//an implementation of the XO board and the game logic
//imports necessary for this class
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
//class definition for drawing a game board
class XOBoard extends Pane 
{
//constructor for the class
public XOBoard(XOUltimateBoard ultimate1) 
{

    this.ultimate1 = ultimate1;
        // Initialise the boards
        board = new int[3][3];
        // renders is an array that holds the 'render pieces'
        renders = new XOPiece[3][3];
        // initialise the rectangle
         back = new Rectangle();
        // add the rectangle
        getChildren().addAll(back);

    //init the board
    board = new int[3][3];
    renders = new XOPiece[3][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            board[i][j] = EMPTY;
            renders[i][j] = null;
        }


    back = new Rectangle();
    back.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    h1 = new Line(); h2 = new Line();
    v1 = new Line(); v2 = new Line();
    h1.setStroke(Color.WHITE); h2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    v1.setStroke(Color.WHITE); v2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

    //horazontal lines 
    h1.setStartX(0); h1.setStartY(0); h1.setEndY(0);
    h2.setStartX(0); h2.setStartY(0); h2.setEndY(0);

    //vertical lines
    v1.setStartX(0); v1.setStartY(0); v1.setEndX(0);
    v2.setStartX(0); v2.setStartY(0); v2.setEndX(0);

    //translation of one cell height and two cell heights
    ch_one = new Translate(0,0);
    ch_two = new Translate(0,0);
    h1.getTransforms().add(ch_one);
    h2.getTransforms().add(ch_two);

    //translation of one cell height and two cell heights
    cw_one = new Translate(0,0);
    cw_two = new Translate(0,0);
    v1.getTransforms().add(cw_one);
    v2.getTransforms().add(cw_two);       

    //add rectangle and lines to this group 
    getChildren().addAll(back,h1,h2,v1,v2);
}


// we have to override resizing behaviour to make our view appear properly
@Override
public void resize(double width, double height) 
{
    //call the superclass method first
    super.resize(width, height);

    // figure out the width and height of a cell
    cell_width = width / 3.0;
    cell_height = height / 3.0;

    //resize the rectangle to take the full size of the widget
    back.setWidth(width); back.setHeight(height);

    //set a new y on the horizontal lines and translate them in to place 
    ch_one.setY(cell_height); ch_two.setY(2 * cell_height);
    h1.setEndX(width); h2.setEndX(width);

    //set a new x on the vertical lines and translate them into place
    cw_one.setX(cell_width); cw_two.setX(2 * cell_width);
    v1.setEndX(height); v2.setEndX(height);

    // we need to reset the sizes and positions of all XOPieces that were placed
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if(board[i][j] != 0) 
            {
                renders[i][j].relocate(i * cell_width, j * cell_height);
                renders[i][j].resize(cell_width, cell_height);
            }


        }
    }

}



//public method for resetting the game
public void resetGame() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
            getChildren().remove(renders[i][j]);
            renders[i][j]= null;
        }
    }
}

//public method that tries to place a piece
public void placePiece(final double x, final double y)
{   
    // translate the x, y coordinates into cell indexes
    int indexx = (int) (x / cell_width);
    int indexy = (int) (y / cell_height);

    // if the position is empty then place a piece and swap the players
    if(board[indexx][indexy] == XPIECE) //toke this out  == EMPTY && current_player 
    {       
        // board is the array that holds all the pieces
        board[indexx][indexy] = XPIECE;
        // Create a new XPIECE
        renders[indexx][indexy] = new XOPiece(XPIECE);
        renders[indexx][indexy].resize(cell_width, cell_height);
        renders[indexx][indexy].relocate(indexx * cell_width,indexy * cell_height);
        // Place an X on the board at position x,y
        getChildren().add(renders[indexx][indexy]);
        this.ultimate1.setCurrent_player(OPIECE);


    }   
else if(board[indexx][indexy]== OPIECE) //toke this out  == EMPTY &&        current_player 
    {
        // board is the array that holds all the pieces
        board[indexx][indexy] = OPIECE;
        // Create a new XPIECE
        renders[indexx][indexy] = new XOPiece(OPIECE);
        renders[indexx][indexy].resize(cell_width, cell_height);
        renders[indexx][indexy].relocate(indexx * cell_width,indexy * cell_height);
        // Place an X on the board at position x,y
        getChildren().add(renders[indexx][indexy]);
        this.ultimate1.setCurrent_player(XPIECE);
    }

}

//private fields of the class
private int[][] board; // array that holds all pieces
private XOPiece[][] renders; // array that holds all the render pieces
private Rectangle back; // background of the board
private final Line h1, h2, v1, v2; // horizontal and vertical grid lines
private double cell_width, cell_height; // width and height of a cell
//translation of {one, two} cell {width, height}
private final Translate ch_one, ch_two, cw_one, cw_two;
// constants for the class
    private final XOUltimateBoard ultimate1;
private final int EMPTY = 0;
private final int XPIECE = 1;
private final int OPIECE = 2;
}
```

and its calling from my XOUltimateBoard class witch is supposed to make the ultimate board game of 3 games * 3 games

```
    package javafxapplicationprototype;

//an implementation of the XO board and the game logic
//imports necessary for this class
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;




//class definition for drawing a game board
class XOUltimateBoard extends Pane 
{
    //constructor for the class
    public XOUltimateBoard() 
    {

    // renders is an array that holds the 'render pieces'
    renders = new XOBoard[3][3];

    // Initialise the boards
    board = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
        board[i][j] = EMPTY;
        renders[i][j] = new XOBoard(this);
        getChildren().add(renders[i][j]);
        }

    }       
    // Current Player is Always X to begin with
    current_player = OPIECE;

}


// override resizing behaviour to make our view appear properly
@Override
public void resize(double width, double height) 
{
    //call the superclass method first
    super.resize(width, height);

    // figure out the width and height of a cell
    cell_width = width / 3.0;
    cell_height = height / 3.0;

    // reset the sizes and positions of all XOPieces that were placed
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if(board[i][j] != 0) 
            {
                renders[i][j].relocate(i * cell_width, j * cell_height);
                renders[i][j].resize(cell_width, cell_height);
            }

        }
    }

}



//public method for resetting the game
public void resetGame() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
            getChildren().remove(renders[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// Return the current player
public int getCurrent_player(){
    return current_player;
}

// Set the current player
public void setCurrent_player(int current_player){
    this.current_player = current_player;
}

//public method that tries to place a piece
public void placePiece(final double x, final double y)
{   
    //x and y store the coordinates of where the user clicked on the board
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);

    // all cells have a constant height and width
    System.out.println(cell_width);
    System.out.println(cell_height);

    // translate the x, y coordinates into cell indexes
    int indexx = (int) (x / cell_width);
    int indexy = (int) (y / cell_height);

    System.out.println("indexx y and indexx x :");
    System.out.println(indexx);
    System.out.println(indexy);


    // if the position is empty then place a piece and swap the players
    if(board[indexx][indexy] == EMPTY && current_player == XPIECE) 
    {
        System.out.println("Value of board[indexx][indexy] IS..."+XPIECE);

        // board is the array that holds all the pieces
        board[indexx][indexy] = XPIECE;


        System.out.println("board[indexx][indexy]....");
        System.out.println(board[indexx][indexy]);
        // Create a new XPIECE
        //renders[indexx][indexy] = new XOPiece(XPIECE);
        // Place an X on the board at position x,y
        getChildren().add(renders[indexx][indexy]);
        current_player = OPIECE;
    }

    else if(board[indexx][indexy] == EMPTY && current_player == OPIECE) 
    {
        board[indexx][indexy] = OPIECE;
        System.out.println("Value of OPIECE IS...");
        System.out.println(OPIECE);
        //renders[indexx][indexy] = new XOPiece(OPIECE);
        getChildren().add(renders[indexx][indexy]);
        current_player = XPIECE;
    }



}

//private fields of the class
private final int[][] board; // array that holds all pieces
private final XOBoard[][] renders; // array that holds all the render pieces
private double cell_width, cell_height; // width and height of a cell
// translation of {one, two} cell {width, height}
private int current_player; // who is the current player
// constants for the class
private final int EMPTY = 0;
private final int XPIECE = 1;
private final int OPIECE = 2;

}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. It is more probable you get some help when you extract only essential parts and precise question.

Comment: did you see the link that i posted of what shows up when the code is running (blank GUI). but my code states that its supposed to have a black background with white vertical and horizontal lines.. i am not sure where i have gone wrong thats why i posed the both classes..

Comment: I'm just trying to tell you that not many people is going to read your code because there is plenty of it.

Comment: Maybe it's because there's a lot of code, but I can't find the code where you actually show the stage with your `XOUltimateBoard` class. See the [Application documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) on how to add your `Pane` to a `Scene` and then set that scene as the scene of the primary stage.

Comment: thanks for the heads up @kacper but i cant narrow it down as it looks all correct to me?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working - I wrote a simple main class that just displayed it and it hung completely without even showing the `Stage`. I would strongly not recommend subclassing `Pane` and managing the layout yourself like this. Just use grid panes: they are designed exactly for this layout, and keep references to them in your classes instead of subclassing them. You simply don't know (and neither do I) enough details of the implementation of the layout mechanism to subclass like this. I suspect the layout is never properly valid, so the layout methods are being called indefinitely.

Comment: thanks very much @James_D i will try and change the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the code you posted won't work. However, the approach you used here - subclassing `Pane` and managing the layout yourself - is probably not a good approach for this kind of layout. The problem (one that is common to subclassing library classes) is you don't really have enough information to know how layout is performed - e.g. when is `resize(..)` invoked, say, in relation to `layoutChildren()`, etc. It is likely you are just causing some infinite loop which is preventing rendering from progressing.

Instead, consider making your classes use composition instead of inheritance, and use existing layouts. A `GridPane` has all the functionality you need here. You can use CSS styling to provide the colors and gaps between the colors, etc.

Here is how I would approach the layout and style:

XOPiece.java:

```
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class XOPiece {

    private final StackPane view ;

    public XOPiece() {
        view = new StackPane();
        view.getStyleClass().add("xo-piece");
    }

    // functionality to maintain state of piece (empty, O, or X) and
    // add content to view as state changes, etc.

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

XOBoard.java:

```
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;

public class XOBoard {
    private final GridPane view ;

    public XOBoard() {
        view = new GridPane();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setPercentWidth(100.0/3);
            view.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setPercentHeight(100.0/3);
            view.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }

        for (int x = 0 ; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < 3; y++) {
                XOPiece piece = new XOPiece();
                view.add(piece.getView(), x, y);
                GridPane.setFillHeight(piece.getView(), true);
                GridPane.setFillWidth(piece.getView(), true);
                piece.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("top"), y==0);
                piece.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("bottom"), y==2);
                piece.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("left"), x==0);
                piece.getView().pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("right"), x==2);             
            }
        }

        view.getStyleClass().add("xo-board");
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

XOUltimateBoard.java

```
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;

public class XOUltimateBoard {

    private final GridPane view ;

    private static final int ROWS = 3 ;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 3 ;

    private final XOBoard[][] boards ;

    public XOUltimateBoard() {
        view = new GridPane();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setPercentWidth(100.0/COLUMNS);
            view.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < ROWS; i++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setPercentHeight(100.0/ROWS);
            view.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }

        boards = new XOBoard[COLUMNS][ROWS];

        for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < ROWS ; y++) {
                boards[x][y] = new XOBoard();
                view.add(boards[x][y].getView(), x, y);
                GridPane.setFillWidth(boards[x][y].getView(), true);
                GridPane.setFillHeight(boards[x][y].getView(), true);
            }
        }


        view.getStyleClass().add("ultimate-board");
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new XOUltimateBoard().getView());
        scene.getStylesheets().add("ultimate-board.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

ultimate-board.css

```css
.ultimate-board {
    -fx-hgap: 10 ;
    -fx-vgap: 10 ;
    -fx-min-width: 400 ;
    -fx-min-height: 400 ;
}
.xo-board {
    -fx-background-color: black ;
}
.xo-board-line {
    -fx-stroke: white ;
}
.xo-piece {
    -fx-background-color: white, black ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 ;
}
.xo-piece:top {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 1 ;
}
.xo-piece:bottom {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1 ;
}
.xo-piece:left {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 1 0 ;
}
.xo-piece:right {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1 ;
}
.xo-piece:top:left {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 0 ;
}
.xo-piece:top:right {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 1 ;
}
.xo-piece:bottom:left {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 0 ;
}
.xo-piece:bottom:right {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 0 1 ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much. can i ask you though i was under the impression that it can be done with out using css?. was i completely wrong?  id love to put up all my code to show you what i was trying to accomplish.

Comment: All of the CSS properties have direct equivalents using Java. E.g. you would do `view.setHgap(10);` and `view.setVgap(10);` in `XOUltimateBoard`. The backgrounds are represented by a [`Background`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) containing two [`BackgroundFill`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundFill.html), and you would just adjust the insets of the second (black) background fill in the same way as the CSS does.

Comment: James_D i am sorry i thought i had ticked the tick but i must have tried to vote it up.. my bad